# How to dynamically create a Material 3 Tonal Button?

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components

I have tried a number of variations of `new MaterialButton(context)` including `new MaterialButton(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_Material3_Button_TonalButton))` but it always results in a standard Material Button (Material 3).

Looking at the original [source](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton.java), the constructor doesn't seem to allow for a `style` resource:

`public MaterialButton(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) { super(wrap(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, DEF_STYLE_RES), attrs, defStyleAttr);`

If my understanding of the `wrap` method is correct, it seems to create a `ContextThemeWrapper` but since the value of `DEF_STYLE_RES` (which is set to `R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_Button`) is always passed in, a default Material Button is always created.

Is there a way to create a Tonal Button by specifying `R.style.Widget_Material3_Button_TonalButton` for the `defStyleRes` parameter? Alternatively, how would I go about dynamically creating a Material 3 Tonal Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
MaterialButton(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Widget_Material3_Button_TonalButton))
```

you are applying a **themeoverlay** to the default style, you are not applying a different style.

It means something like:

```
<style name="Widget.Material3.Button.TonalButton" parent="">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
    <!-- .... ->
</style>
```

The 3rd parameter of the constructor is `defStyleAttr` and it is an **attribute** defined in your app theme, it is **not** a style. If you want to apply a **different style** you have to:

- Define a custom attribute in `attrs.xml`

```xml
    <attr name="myButtonStyle" format="reference"/>
```

- Assing a style to this attribute in your app theme:

```xml
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.*">
        <item name="myButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.Button.TonalButton</item>
   </style>
```

Finally use:

```
val customButton = MaterialButton(context, null, R.attr.myButtonStyle)
```

Comment: I considered this approach but having seen the existence of attributes such as "materialButtonOutlinedStyle" I thought I was missing something as a "materialButtonTonalStyle" didn't exist which led me to believe there was an alternative way of creating a Tonal button. As a side note, is there any reason a "materialButtonTonalStyle" doesn't exist in the "material-components" library?

Comment: @user959631 I don't know. You can open an issue in the [github repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues) to know if there is a reason.